# Kill supervisord once all processes it is running exited successfully in docker

Tags: docker, containers, supervisord

I went through numerous blogs, articles but didn't find satisfactory solution so posting here. Excuse me if it is already discussed or answered. Please direct me to the relevant pages.
**I got answers on how to kill supervisord if one of the process fails/exits, but when all processes exited then how to stop/kill supervisord.**

We have 3 python processes running inside a docker using supervisord. I have found when all program gets exited successfully still my container is running as supervisord process is running which is the main PID1.

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

How can I kill/stop supervisord, so that container will automatically pull down?

Comment: Why not run this as three separate containers, without supervisord?  That should easily be able to handle the process lifecycle you want.

Comment: We have most of our script working with supervisord, we want to use the same in docker with minimal changes. All 3 processes use the same python script with same dependencies, only they work differently based on arguments. 
Supervisor works fine anyway, it triggers the script, closes the script once job is done but supervisord runs thereafter in the background.
If we won't find any workarounds then finally we are going to use multiple containers.

Comment: In general you should try to run one process per container, and it's fine to run multiple containers from the same image with different commands or environment variables.

Comment: Yes, we will be using multiple containers but curiosity still there on how to shut down supervisord once all inside processes are completed.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

1. Add below in supervisord.conf

```
[eventlistener:processes]
command=/bin/bash -c ". /etc/stop-supervisor.sh"
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED, PROCESS_STATE_EXITED, PROCESS_STATE_FATAL, PROCESS_STATE_UNKNOWN, PROCESS_STATE_BACKOFF
```

2./etc/stop-supervisor.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "READY\n";

while read line; do
  echo "Processing Event: $line" >&2;
  kill -3 $(cat "/data/logs/supervisord.pid")
done < /dev/stdin
```

replace pid file location in /etc/stop-supervisor.sh with your's.